# Angular good practices for names model

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 7 and I have a doubt about the good practices for the names:

When I declare a service like `cat.services.ts` I write on the service:

```
export class CatServices
{
[...]
}
```

And on the component I use `CatServices`:

```
[...]
private  catServices: CatServices;

  constructor
  (
    private catServices: CatServices,
  )
[...]
```

But for the model can I concatenate the name of the model like Hero and the key `Model` (like for the service and component)?

For instance:

```
export interface HeroModel
{
[...]
}
```

Is it right or no? And why?
I have read the [doc](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) but I have not understood very well for the model part names.

Comment: `can I concatenate the name of the model like Hero and the key Model...` ← Yes, why couldn't you? Or are you asking "should" you instead of "can" you (one means is it a good practice, the other is it technically possible). If the question is "should" you then the answer will vary but ultimately is rooted in opinion and thus the question is not a good candidate for [so].

Comment: Yes, I can, but  I wish to know if it is a good practices or no (that's all)

Comment: That depends on you. My personal preference is to name models similar to this but I am sure there are other devs. out there that have their own naming preferences / conventions.

Comment: Ok, thanks so I can (and should) named the model with: name+model like HeroModel. Is it right?

Comment: No you shouldn't, you just can, because as Igor said, everyone have it's own naming preferences. For example I prefer not adding the "Model" after because I prefer when my model is perfectly corresponding with my database name. So if you prefer to add it, do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a model basically you create an interface and a good practice is to name the interface with a leading "I" in the name so othercguys working on the same project knows that it is a custom interface created.

Example: ICat, IHero etc.